# using this keyword dojo module event handler

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have a dojo module and I want to use **this** keyword but have some issue.

```
 require(["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/_base/lang","dojo/query", "dojo/on",
          "dojo/dom", "dojo/NodeList-traverse"], 
         function(declare, lang, query, on, dom, nls) {

             var mainWidget = declare(null,{
                constructor:function(){
                    this.onItemClicked = lang.hitch(this, this.onItemClicked);        

                    on(dom.byId("myList"), ".toggle:click", this.onItemClicked);
                },

                onItemClicked: function (event) {
                   dom.byId("result").innerHTML =  this._calculate();
                   dom.byId("result").innerHTML = query(this).parent('li');
                },

                _calculate:function(){
                  return 10 * 10;
                }
            });

            var wg = new mainWidget();   

});
```

I want to use **this** keyword in **onItemClicked** event handler. I want to access a methot named _**calculate** that out of event handler method. And I want to access **query(this)** object

this._calculate() is working but query(this) should return  element but does not return.

This is [jsfiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/barteloma/eL7mB/3/) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understand well, the `this` context should be both the widget (for the `_calculate()` function) and the DOM node that was clicked (for the `query()` function)?

That's really a big bad practice. You want to refer to two objects using a single context, not only does it sound bad, it makes your code unreadable.

Just use the event handler's `target` property to retrieve the clicked element, just like this:

```
dom.byId("result").innerHTML += query(event.target).parent('li');
```

But don't forget that you're overriding your `#result` HTML because you're using:

```
dom.byId("result").innerHTML = ...;
```

If you want to add it next to the calculated value (`100`), then use the `+=` operator.

---

**Small note**: You can use the `this` context for both the widget and the target element by combining both objects, but like I said, that's not a good idea to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need somehow to capture the context you want. A higher order function is a nice way to accomplish that:

```
dojo.connect(window, "onload", function(){
  require(["dojo/_base/declare",
      "dojo/_base/lang",
      "dojo/query",
      "dojo/on",
      "dojo/dom",
      "dojo/NodeList-traverse"], 
     function(declare, lang, query, on, dom, nls) {
        var createBtnClicked = function(context){
             return function(){
               dom.byId("result").innerHTML = context._calculate();
               dom.byId("result").innerHTML = query(this).parent('li');
             };
         }

         var mainWidget = declare(null,{
            constructor: function(){
                //this.onBtnClicked = lang.hitch(this, this.onBtnClicked);        

                on(dom.byId("myList"), ".toggle:click, .toggle:keyup", createBtnClicked(this));
            },

            _calculate:function(){
              return 10 * 10;
            }
        });

        var wg = new mainWidget();   
});
```

Check it here http://fiddle.jshell.net/eL7mB/11/